# How do I drag formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need help with with Excel on trying to drag the formula down without having to copy and paste all the time

Example:

```
       Column A
Row1  =(A1/A2)*100
Row2  =(A3/A4)*100
Row3  =(A5/A6)*100
       etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely looking for is some combination of [`INDIRECT`](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/ss/2013-08-07-excel-sum-indirect-dynamic-range-formula.htm) and [`ROW()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/row-HP005209244.aspx).

Something like:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & (ROW() * 2 - 1)) / INDIRECT("A" & (ROW() * 2 )) * 100
```

`INDIRECT()` allows you to specify a range dynamically (in this case, if you're on row 1, `ROW()` will resolve to `1`, which gives you `=INDIRECT("A1")/INDIRECT("A2") * 100)`.

Edit: I presented this formula and rationale based on the description in the original question, wherein the formula results in:

```
Row1  =(A1/A2)*100
Row2  =(A3/A4)*100
Row3  =(A5/A6)*100
```

However, I do see that the question could also be a general one about how to extend a formula across a range of cells, which was addressed by @eleethesontai.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the cell that you want to copy on the bottom right hand of the black box that will appear on the cell will be a little black box select that and drag the formula down. Alternatively you can copy the cell u want to use them select the cells u want copied to right click paste special formula.

Comment: This increments the row references by one.  The question specifies the rows incremented by two (unless it was asked incorrectly).

Comment: your right fixer1234.  I spoke to soon i made the assumption he was just asking for how to fill a formula down.  Im sorry.